# What does the '...' operator do in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading an [image processing tutorial](https://innat.github.io/innat.github.io/Image-Processing-in-Python-Part-1/) and came across this line of python:

```
gray = lambda rgb : np.dot(rgb[... , :3] , [0.299 , 0.587, 0.114])
```

What does the '...' operator do in this case?

Comment: `rgb[]` is not a list, it's a subscript/item access on `rgb`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know what the ... operator was called ellipses. So searching for it  explicitly did not yield the correct answer.

Comment: It's not an operator, it's a special, singleton value like `None`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification